# How to completely customize the way that type information gets written to a document by Spring Data MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, polymorphism, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

Is it possible to use different type attribute (instead of `_class`) for each polymorphic collection like it's implemented in Doctrine(PHP) or Jackson libraries? Current solution allows to store type information in document field. By default it is a full class name stored in the field named `_class`.

We can easy change it to save some custom string (alias) instead of full class name and change default discriminator field name from `_class` to something else.

In my situation I'm working on legacy database while legacy application is still in use. Legacy application uses Doctrine (PHP) ODM as datalayer.
Doctrine allows to define discriminator field name (`_class` in SpringData) by annotation and have it **different for each collection**.

In Spring Data when I pass typeKey to DefaultMongoTypeMapper it used for **all collections**.

Thanks.

```
// MyCustomMongoTypeMapper.java
// ...

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public <T> TypeInformation<? extends T> readType(DBObject source, TypeInformation<T> basicType) {

    Assert.notNull(basicType);
    Class<?> documentsTargetType = null;

    Class<? super T> parent = basicType.getType();
    while (parent != null && parent != java.lang.Object.class) {
        final String discriminatorKey = getDiscriminatorKey(parent); //fetch key from annotation
        if (null == discriminatorKey) {
            parent = parent.getSuperclass();
        } else {
            accessor.setKey(discriminatorKey);
            return super.readType(source, basicType);
        }
    }
    accessor.resetKey();
    return super.readType(source, basicType);
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you're trying to achieve? What exactly would you like to be able to do? Why does the solution currently available not work for you?

Comment: Please see the question update.

Comment: That helps, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something that should work for you is completely exchanging the `MongoTypeMapper` instance that `MappingMongoConverter` uses. As you discovered the already available implementation assumes a common field name and takes yet another strategy to either write the fully-qualified class name or an alias or the like.

However, you should be able to just write your own and particularly focus on the following methods:

- `void writeType(TypeInformation<?> type, DBObject dbObject)` — you basically get the type and have complete control over where and how to put that into the DBObject.
- `<T> TypeInformation<? extends T> readType(DBObject source, TypeInformation<T> defaultType);` — you get the type declared on the reading side (i.e. usually the most common type of the hierarchy) and based on that have to lookup the type from the given source document. I guess that's exactly the inverse of what's to be implemented in the other method.

On a final note, I would strongly recommend against using different type field names for different collections as on the reading side you might run into places where just `Object` is declared on the property and you basically don't get no clue where to even look for in the document.

Comment: Is it good to modify your DBObjectTypeAliasAccessor: add setter for the typeKey and in my write/read methods implementation just set the key fetched from class annotation before calling the super method?  I updated the question with example.

Comment: Whatever works for you :). I basically wanted to give you a hint at which places to look and point out that in the worst case you can just implement the interface. Not sure I am eager to make that more comfortable as — as indicated in the last paragraph — I don't think that's something you should really do unless absolutely necessary and we actually can make this work for all cases.

Comment: I agree with you regarding different type field name and my first suggestion was to bring it to common name in legacy application. But it more political than technical decision... :)  Thanks for your help!

Comment: @OliverDrotbohm: How do you suggest to implement different strategies for different collections, which use the same document property as class instance discriminator? For example, I have two collections: `students` and `pupils` and I have a property `sex` in every document in each of these collections with possible values `[male, female]`. For collections `students` I would like to create instances of `MaleStudent and FemaleStudent`. And `MalePupil` / `FemalePupil` correspondingly for collection `pupils`.